# Create one to one relation using code first approch in entitiy framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5, entity-relationship

I have below two classes and i wanted to make a one to one relation between these two entities using Code First approch. Anybody can suggest/help me on how to create ONE to ONE relation between these Patient & Address entities ? Thanks in advance...

```
public partial class Patient
{
    public Patient()
    {
        this.Clinicals = new List<Clinical>();
    }

    public int PatientId { get; set; }
    public string MaritalStatus { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Clinical> Clinicals { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
}


public partial class Address
{        
    public int AddressId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Patient")]
    public int PatientId { get; set; }
    public string AddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you run your application Entity Framework will create `one-to-one` relationship automatically for you.Because you have added necessary properties for this. Anyway, if you want to create it manually you can use [Fluent API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591620.aspx#RequiredToRequired):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Patient>()
    .HasRequired(a => a.Address)
    .WithRequiredPrincipal(p => p.Patient);
```